# Pygame exiting fullscreen mode sets window outside screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem when going from fullscreen mode to a smaller screen in Pygame. The window appears on the top left and I can't see any exit button, nor can I drag it to the center. Here is the code I am using:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            # Exit fullscreen with escape key
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:

                if screen.get_flags() & FULLSCREEN:
                    pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
                else:
                    pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), FULLSCREEN)
```

I have tried to center the smaller window on the screen which usually works fine, but not in this case.

```
import os

# .........
                if screen.get_flags() & FULLSCREEN:
                    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
                    pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
                else:
                    pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), FULLSCREEN)
```

Any ideas how to center the window after exiting fullscreen?

Comment: I ran to the same issue by the past. I avoided that by adding the [`SCALED`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) tag to my window. Now the window is still visible (but it now goes at the top left corner of the screen...)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in pygame.

If you need this behavior, someone who reported the issue on github found a workaround (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2360)

Hopefully it'll be fixed in 2.0.2, I've written a patch to fix it (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2460)